# Cheap Online Shopping for Small Consumables?

Tags: maintenance, product-rec, frugal, shopping

I am looking for different types of lubricants, chains, small metal parts such as a Tubus rack-hinge and just small things that wear easily off -- so-called consumables. I am fed up to high prices locally, usually better to buy new stuff, reusing to the dogs. Which online shopping sites do you use for your small consumables?

Comment: Please remember that if you are buying "cheap" that you (or we) are probably paying full price somewhere down the line.  I don't doubt that someone somewhere is charging too much for a Tubus rack-hinge.  I also realize, though, that such an object has a cost of manufacture and some price must be charged in order to keep the dealer and the manufactuerer in business.  If you are getting it online for some ridiculous low-price, it may be a knock-off manufactuered in some place where they treat their workers and OUR environment like snot.  It also may be stolen or just plain low-quality junk.

Comment: Just research more than price and type of object is all I'm saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small consumables I tend to use the same places as for the large ones: if I'm going online it will be mainly to [Wiggle](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/) or [Chain Reaction](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/) (I'm UK-based, so these might not ship or be as competitively priced in other locales).

I do try and [support my LBS](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/how-should-i-negotiate-price-with-bicycle-salespeople/2031#2031), though, even if they're more expensive: better to pay 10% more and have the option of a well-stocked, local physical shop for urgent needs (or a slow chat) than save a bit of cash but left up a tree in the next emergency, but sometimes online savings are just too much to ignore ...

Comment: wiggle do free international shipping if you spend about $100

Answer (score 0):

[nashbar.com](http://www.nashbar.com)

[amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com) (they have everything it seems)

[pricepoint.com](http://www.pricepoint.com)

I will also use a "shopping bot" like Google Shopping if I know the exact brand of what I am looking for.  It will often find deals from online shops that I didn't even know about.