# When to buy an enduro bike: autumn or spring?

Tags: mountain-bike, price

> [At what time of year can I buy a bicycle for the best price?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/170/at-what-time-of-year-can-i-buy-a-bicycle-for-the-best-price)

Here is some more information for my specific case.

- I live in Bulgaria, and as the bike needs to be tested, purchasing from abroad is not an option.
- It is early autumn now, and the prices have already dropped, that is 20% off Trek bikes, and other bikes have fallen e.g. 5000BGN->3500BGN; 12000BGN->8000BGN
- Budget between 2000-4000BGN (I would like to stay away from the steep region in the price/quality chart, but still have the money for a good bike)
- Scott, Trek, Specialized, Giant, RAM, Shockblaze are the most prominent brands here i.e. most bikes in the shops are from those brands
- Target riding stile is climb+trail, climb+ski track downhill (summertime), maybe ramps later
- The showroom bikes that are at reduced cost seem not ridden at all, probably due to the high cost
- From the moment that I make the decision, it will be probably around a couple of weeks until I try most bike shops locally and choose a model
- I will not be riding this winter, however storage in an apartment is not an issue
- The bike will be used only for MTB, I have a separate commuter bike

I am worried that at early spring, when the new models arrive, the **old promotions might be dropped**. Those promotions are quite substantial. **At what point (now or in spring) would I be best off, buying a bike?**

Quick currency converter: 4 392BGN == Trek Slash 7
[image]

Comment: Sometimes it depends on the bike shop.  Many shops in my area try to clear out the bikes in the fall, to clear up floor space for skis or other winter sports.  Other bike shops are exclusively bike shops and will only clear out the bikes when the newer models become available in the spring.

Comment: I'm not clear what it is that you're asking that hasn't already been answered in the question that you linked to.

Comment: @jimirings, will they discard those promotions in spring, or deepen them? What is more likely? I do not have LBS that I trust so much as to believe they will answer me, without considering their business interests foremost (i.e. everyone would say "buy now, out most expensive bike :D")

Comment: In the US you can usually find some really good bargains (30-50% off) in the early fall.  Whether they deepen the discounts in the spring or raise prices back depends on whether the model is discontinued or not.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks, could you elaborate on this? When would they reset the prices and when would they deepen the discount and when would the discount stay the same until sold. I really need to ask around locally.

Comment: Prices will drop as the winter goes on, but don't forget that choice will drop also. A couple of years ago, in the week before christmas, I bought an excellent audax bike at about 60% off. My timing was accidental but I did learn that by then there were only 2 of these bikes (in my size a very average 54) available in the UK. (I test rode the same frame, then bought the better groupset which was delivered to shop from factory.) I happened to luck out, but if you have a specific bike in mind you might take the view that that's cutting things a bit fine.

Comment: @Vorac - As PeterH suggests, there are no "rules" -- the shops will drop prices to keep their sales floor busy and (maybe) to get rid of "old" stock that will be worth even less come spring because of the new products.  Basically, you're playing a game of what's called "chicken" in the US -- two cars driving toward each other to see which driver loses his nerve and swerves off first.  (Only at least in this case a misjudgement is not as disastrous.)  Some shops (mostly the larger ones, with other product lines) do this aggressively, some hardly at all.

Comment: The best time to buy a bike is today.  Life's only so-long, and delaying by 6 months is time wasted, that could be spent riding.

Answer (score 2):

Generally late fall (when new bike are arriving on dealers showrooms) or in the middle of winter (when dealers want to move inventory just to help cash flow).

Of course, the older a bike is, the more likely it is to be discounted, but it will also be less likely that you will find the size/spec. that you want.